# Using `clear:both` inside a `::before` pseudo-element

Tags: css, css-float, pseudo-element

I can't figure out why this isn't working:

```css
my-selector::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:  both;
}
```

I'm using floats into a wide, styled border to keep meta information out of the flow of the main content (This is an attempt to implement something like the [Cornell Notetaking System](https://lsc.cornell.edu/how-to-study/taking-notes/cornell-note-taking-system/); any suggestions for how to do this better would be appreciated, but I still want to know why this technique is failing!)  When I have a meta note (aka `cue`), it simply gets the class `cue` and is floated left.

(Note that I don't have easy direct control of the HTML; it's generated from a Markdown-like language.  But I can add the `cue` class.)

This works well, so long as the cues are shorter than the succeeding code they annotate:

```css
div.Cornell {
  padding: 0 1em;
  border-left: 12em solid #cfc;
}
div.Cornell div.cue {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: -12em;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.Cornell div.cue::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:  both;
}
.Cornell-summary {
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: #ffe;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="Cornell">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Sapien eget mi proin sed.</p>

<div class="cue">
  <p>First cue: <em>Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate.  Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus.</em></p>
</div>

<p>The first cue should float left of this content.</p>

<p>Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui. Purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum. Purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor.</p>

<div class="cue"><p>Second cue: <em>Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris</em></p></div>

<p>The second cue should float left of this content</p>

<p>Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget.</p>
</div>
<div class="Cornell-summary">
<hr/>
<h2>Summary</h2>
<p>Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec.</p>
</div>
```

But when the cue content is longer, it causes issues.  The floated content simply overlaps.  I thought I would be able to solve this with the `::before` pseudo-element and `clear: both`, but as you can see here, it doesn't seem to work:

```css
div.Cornell {
  padding: 0 1em;
  border-left: 12em solid #cfc;
}
div.Cornell div.cue {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: -12em;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.Cornell div.cue::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:  both;
}
.Cornell-summary {
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: #ffe;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="Cornell">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Sapien eget mi proin sed.</p>

<div class="cue">
  <p>First cue: <em>Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate.  Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus.</em></p>
  <p>Sed cras ornare arcu dui. Erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin. Orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae.</p>
</div>

<p>The first cue should float left of this content.</p>

<p>Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui. Purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum. Purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor.</p>

<div class="cue"><p>Second cue: <em>Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris</em></p></div>

<p>The second cue should float left of this content</p>

<p>Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget.</p>
</div>
<div class="Cornell-summary">
<hr/>
<h2>Summary</h2>
<p>Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec.</p>
</div>
```

Am I missing something simple?  Something more complex but doable?  It really feels as if this *should* work.

This output is what I was trying to achieve, but using hard-coded additional divs that have `clear: both`:

```css
div.Cornell {
  padding: 0 1em;
  border-left: 12em solid #cfc;
}
div.Cornell div.cue {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: -12em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Cornell-summary {
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: #ffe;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="Cornell">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Sapien eget mi proin sed.</p>

<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div class="cue">
  <p>First cue: <em>Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate.  Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus.</em></p>
  <p>Sed cras ornare arcu dui. Erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin. Orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae.</p>
</div>

<p>The first cue should float left of this content.</p>

<p>Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui. Purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum. Purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor.</p>

<!-- I do understand that this DIV is unnecessary; but having it
     here *works* and I hope it demonstrates what I was trying to
     do with my `::before` syntax.  --> 
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div class="cue"><p>Second cue: <em>Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris</em></p></div>

<p>The second cue should float left of this content</p>

<p>Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget.</p>
</div>
<div class="Cornell-summary">
<hr/>
<h2>Summary</h2>
<p>Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As you said, you might miss something simple. That is why I tried. Simple things I may find.  https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/8ek03sb4/6/ Is that of help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the desired outcome is. Is the main text corresponding to the second cue supposed to get pushed down when the first cue text is long?

Comment: we clear float after them, not inside them (cue is floating, so the clear need to be after it)

Comment: @deEr.: That seems to have the same behavior as my second example.  The floating sections overlap (at least in Chrome.)

Comment: @j08691: Yes, and I'll add one more example that demonstrates what I would like, but with hard-coded additional `clear: both` DIVS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Note my additional example.  By clearing any floats before the next cue,  we achieve the result I want.  But it requires adding markup that I don't have available in this dynamically generated HTML.

Comment: For me it worked at Chrome, but -- not -- at Edge. This does both: https://jsfiddle.net/v10ub3r8/ .

Comment: @DeEr.: I no longer get the overlap, but the content does not stay aligned.  See the third example I added to show the desired output.

Comment: you are not clearing *before*, float doesn't work like that. The first div you added is not needed you can remove and the second one is clearing the first float. As you can read in the duplicate, you need to clear float after and the clear need to be placed after the element

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I don't have a wrapper element to attach a `clear:both` element on, just a series of DIV / P elements.  I understand that the first one is not necessary, but it also *works* when I add the `clear:both` to a DIV right before my `.cue` element.  I'm trying to duplicate that effect with `::before` on the `.cue` element as that is the only hook that my generated markup offers.  I guess another way of asking this is, "Can we attach any CSS to the markup in my second example to achieve the layout of my third one?"

Comment: Close voter(s): I do understand clearfix, and have used them for years.  I just don't understand why my `::before` pseudo-element with a `clear: both` does not clear the floats that have come before.

Comment: Got you. I memorized the 30 CSS selectors you must memorize: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048t And I think I found a simple `+` https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/8ek03sb4/16/  

Comment: `::before` doesn't mean "before the element" it means "inside the element and before it's content" and you cannot clear a float element by clearing inside it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: thank you.  That was a subtlety I was missing.  Hmm.  I'm not trying to clear the current element but the floats that came before it.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223841/is-it-safe-to-apply-clear-both-to-clearfixbefore

Comment: @TylerH: Thank you.  Yes, that states clearly what Temani got through my thick skull in these comments, and which I just explained in an answer (now that this has been re-opened: thanks!)

Comment: I just spent ages writing up a solution and now I cannot post it. XD @ScottSauyet if this solution suits you, could you re-open the question so I can post it? See comments about optionally moving paragraphs below cues https://codepen.io/jakesidsmith/pen/eYoOaJw

Comment: @JakeSidSmith: I didn't close this.  I'm guessing that TylerH did so.  I can't even nominate it to be reopened, because I did so once before, and it was opened very briefly, while I added my answer and responded to Tyler's comment.  Feel free to share a link in chat to JSBin, JSFiddle, CodePen, ReplIT, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment thread got long, so I will summarize here.

What I was trying to do is impossible.  The following creates a pseudo-element, but it does not appear in the DOM before the focused element.  It appears before the *content* of that element:

```css
my-selector::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:  both;
}
```

Thus I was trying to clear the float I was actually inside; it doesn't make sense.

Thanks to everyone who helped clear that up, most especially @TemaniAfif!

---

I did solve my underlying problem.  I had said that I couldn't control the markup that was generated from the underlying language.  But it turns out that if you look hard enough, you *can* add a custom markup element.  Then it was simple to generate a clearing DIV before my new floating content, and everything works fine.